# How to disallow Scrollview scrolling through stylus?

Tags: android, scrollview, stylus-pen

I have custom scrollview written which is working fine without stylus from Tablets. 
 When using Tablet stylus this customScrollview is allowing stylus to perform scrolling even when Scrolling is disabled.

```
public class CustomScrollView extends ScrollView {

    private boolean enabled = false;

    public CustomScrollView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    public boolean getEnabled() {
        return this.enabled;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overriding onInterceptHoverListener Did the trick. 
Now the Stylus onhover scroll is handled if scrollview is enabled,the same is not handled once the scrollview enabled = false.

```
    public class CustomScrollView extends ScrollView {

        private boolean enabled = false;

        public CustomScrollView(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        public CustomScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
        }

        public CustomScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
            return enabled;
        }

        public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
            this.enabled = enabled;
        }

      @Override
        public boolean onInterceptHoverEvent(MotionEvent event) {
   if (this.enabled)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
          return true;
        }

}

       public boolean getEnabled() {
            return this.enabled;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you could give this a try.

```
 if (MotionEvent.getToolType(TOOL_TYPE_STYLUS))
 { 
 // disable scrollview 
 }
```

Comment: Nope not a good solution @Rick. My problem is not the scrollview. I hope you used stylus in a tablet. So when you point your stylus to end of the home screen it move to the next screen. The same happens in scrollview as well. If something is scrollable on screen , pointing the stylus at the end will make it scroll. I want to stop this from happening. Because the scrollview is disabled  100% sure. But when I point the stylus to the end it starts scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (ev.getToolType(TOOL_TYPE_STYLUS)) { 
        // also, here you should check if it should be disabled at this point
        return !enabled;
    } else {
        return enabled;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope not the right way to do it . Can you please refer to Rick Answer comment section @Dragoslav

Comment: Oh, sorry then, my bad.